# What affects stack size in recursion?

Tags: recursion, stack-overflow

Exactly what parts of a recursive method call contributes to the stack--say, the returned object, arguments, local variables, etc.?

I'm trying to optimize the levels of recursion that an Android application can do on limited memory before running into a StackOverflowException.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run out of stack space, don't optimize your stack usage. Doing that just means the same problem will come back later, with a slightly larger input set or called from somewhere else. And at some point you have reached the theoretical or practical minimum of space you can consume for the problem you're solving. Instead, convert the offending code to use a collection other than the machine stack (e.g. a heap-allocated stack or queue). Doing so sometimes results in very ugly code, but at least it won't crash.

But to answer the question: Generally all the things you name can take stack space, and temporary values take space too (so nesting expressions like crazy just to save local variables won't help). Some of these will be stored in registers, depending on the calling convention, but may have to be spilled(*) anyway. But regardless of the calling convention, this only saves you a few bytes, and everything will have to be spilled for calls as the callee is given usually free reign over registers during the call. So at the time your stack overflows, the stack is indeed crowded with parameters, local variables, and temporaries of earlier calls. Some may be optimized away altogether or share a stack slot if they aren't needed at the same time. Ultimately this is up to the JIT compiler.

(*) Spilling: Moving a value from a register to memory (i.e., the stack) because the register is needed for something else.

Comment: Well, there's no exact solution the the problem that I'm trying to solve--it's just that the more recursion I can carry out, the more accurate the result. I set a hard cap on the number of times the method can be recursively called, but currently, anything more than 23 times causes it to run out of stack space, when I'd like something closer to 75. I was thinking that maybe creating a bunch of static fields and changing those instead of passing in arguments and declaring new variables with each recursive call would reduce the amount of stack space used with each call. Would that work?

Comment: So what? If you move your data from the JVM stack to an explicit data structure (details depends on what you do; a stack is a first approximation but e.g. breadth-first traversal of trees lends itself to a queue) you will not *ever* overflow the stack and can make several orders of magnitude more recursive calls (which equals better solutions in your case). As for static fields: Do you realize the implications for concurrency and testing? Aside from that, the value will still have to be loaded, so it won't help much.

Answer (score 0):

Each method has two stack frame sizes associated with it, the stack required for arguments and local variables, and the stack required for expression evaluation. The return value only counts as part of the stack required for expression evaluation. The JVM is able to verify that the method does not exceed these sizes as it executes.

Exactly how much stack is required for variables and expression evaluation is down to the bytecode compiler. For instance it is often able to share local variable slots among variables with non-overlapping lifetimes.